# how to access this info_config[:hash][key]

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-console

i have a file info.yml that has info like this

```
"email1@gmail.com":
      ame: "Paul"
      from: "VISA-PG-Credit Card Acquittal-"
      project: "001-Admin"
      entity: "01-HTW (Los Angeles)"

"email2@gmail.com"
     name: "Bill"
     from: "VISA-PG-Company"
     project: "005-Admin"
     entity: "01-HTW (Panama)"
```

Now I am  trying to access this info from console. When i try this

```
>>INFO_CONFIG[:"email1@gmail.com"]["project"]
```

it gives me correct result as "001-Admin"
But if i try this as

```
>>sender = "email1@gmail.com"

>>INFO_CONFIG[:sender]["project"]
```

It gives me following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

What is wrong with my syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably use `to_sym` like this:

```
INFO_CONFIG[sender.to_sym]["project"]
```

It seems to do what you want:

```
"email1@gmail.com".to_sym #=> :"email1@gmail.com"
```

Answer (score -1):

You pass in the symbol `:sender` as the array key, but you want the email address (as a string) as the key:

```
sender = "email1@gmail.com"
INFO_CONFIG[sender]['project']
```

Comment: He doesn't want the email address as a string. He wants it as a symbol.